# Android: Alternative to fragments (Performance issues)

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

I'm using tabs to switch pages in a container view. This works smoothly until I fill these pages with different kind of layouts or objects. The performance drops and it gets lower frames per second (no project butter here at all :D).

Can I use something else than fragments for this? Also if I want to keep the information (lets say I input my name on page 1) even when I have switched to another page?

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setTransition( FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE );
    transaction.replace( R.id.container, new FirstFragment() );
    transaction.commit();
```

Each button in my tabsholder has its own fragment to change to.

What is making my performance drop? Is it not removing views? What should I use instead?

This is a rather wide question but I wouldn't know where to turn.

Comment: Have you tried optimizing the layout hierarchies within your fragments?

Comment: This sounds intereseting. Could you provide a good example? I have never heard of it.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html